# Using kebab-case CSS classnames in CSS/SASS modules when using Next js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, next.js

I am using SCSS modules for my components in React/Next.js but I can't figure out how to import kebab-case classes.

At the moment, I am just writing all my SCSS classes in camelCase but this isn't ideal as this means I cannot make use of SCSS cascading.

(I'm still learning React am I'm not so great at making dynamic components myself so I am sticking to React Strap for now.)

Essentially, I want to write

```
.company-logo
```

instead of:

```
.companyLogo
```

**EDIT: `className={styles['company-logo']}` causes an unexpected token error**

Here is my Component:

```
import styles from './styles/Navbar.module.scss'

const NavComponent = (props) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);

  return (
    <div>
      <img src="../ss-logo.png" alt="Logo" className={styles.companyLogo}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default NavComponent;
```

And my SCSS:

```
.companyLogo {
  height: 3rem;
}
```

Comment: Did u solve this.?

Answer (score 15):

```
className={styles['company-logo']}
```

should be what you want.

Comment: Nope, I tried that. It causes an "unexpected token error" :/

Answer (score 5):

You can use the object key `[]` syntax.

```
<img src="..." className={styles['company-logo']}`
```

Comment: Nope, I tried that. It causes an "unexpected token error" :/

Answer (score 3):

```
<img src="../ss-logo.png" alt="Logo" className={`${style['company-logo']}`}/>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Inline:**

```
<img src="../ss-logo.png" alt="Logo" className={`${styles["company-logo"]}`}/>
```

**Variable:**

```
var logo = classNames({
  [`${styles["company-logo"]}`]: true,
});

return (
  <div>
    <img src="../ss-logo.png" alt="Logo" className={logo} />
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bracket notation `[]` to access object with a dash `-` separator:

```html
<img className={styles['company-logo']}/>
```

Additionally, if you want to apply multiple class names, you can use template literals:

```html
<img className={`${styles['company-logo']} ${styles['personal-logo']}`/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes but you will not have autocomplete and go to definition, i am just naming them camelCase in module.css  :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).